# Finding the least-squares line, having trouble finding $S_{xx}$ and $S_{xy}$

Tags: statistics

I'm having trouble understanding the solution for this question

[image]

The solution says that $S_{xx}$ $ = 6000$ and $S_{xy} = -1900$

The formula for $S_{xx} = \sum^n_{i=1} (xi-\overline x)^2$ and for $S_{xy} = \sum^n_{i=1} (xi-\overline x)Yi$

When I do $S_{xx}$ I get $(30-60)^2 + (50-60)^2 + (70-60)^2 + (90-60)^2 = 2000$, and I'm not even sure how to calculate $S_{xy}$ because of the 3 points for each y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a set of twelve points -- so that is actually twelve $x_i$ values; not only four.   It is just that the table didn't list duplicate values, and collected them as a heading.   So...
 $$S_{xx} ~=~ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{12} (x_i-\bar x) ~=~ 3\times 2000 ~=~ 6000$$

---

Second verse, same as the first... mostly....

We are after the sum of the products $(x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y)$ , for each pair of $(x_i,y_i)$ that we have.

Here each of the four (triplicated) $x_i$ values is paired with three $y_i$.   We have twelve products to sum; but we may as well do them in four groups.

$$\begin{align}S_{xy} ~=~& \sum\limits_{(x_i,y_i)}~(x_i-\bar x)(y_i-\bar y) \\[1ex] ~=~ & (30{-}60)\big((38{-}36){+}(43{-}36){+}(29{-}36)\big)+(50{-}60)\big(\ldots)+\ldots\textsf{etc.}\end{align}$$

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you. How about the $S_{xx}$ part? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user270494  You actually have 12 pairs of values -- that is a collection\ of twelve $x_i$ values.  It is just that the table doesn't list the duplicates.  Hence $S_{xx} = 3 \times 2000$